# Audio delay on Safari Desktop

Tags: javascript, html, macos, safari, html5-audio

I have a page with several `<audio>` tags. Whenever I play the audio in Chrome (Desktop, macOS), it starts immediately, while in Safari (13.1, macOS) it waits for some time before starting playing (the weird thing is that it waits longer if they are several audio tags on the page).

I thought that the problem was with the "preload" attribute not set, so I've set it to "auto" according to the docs][1](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/AudioandVideoTagBasics/AudioandVideoTagBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH2-SW9), but it didn't change a thing.

I don't want to use a 3rd party library to keep as as simple as possible.

How can I remove this delay? And why is it longer the more audio tags I have on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to remove the delay completely, but I made it much better by setting `preload` to ="metadata". For some reason it makes files load much quicker for playback.

Chrome actually is smart about this. When the preload is set to auto, it caches around 1mb of each audio file upon page load, so it can play it quicker when you press "Play" button.

I also started listening to `onwaiting` event of the `audio` element, so I can show the preloader to make experience a little bit better.

Since Safari fires `oncanplay` and `onplaying` much sooner when the file is actually ready to play, I don't just hide preloader on this events, but after a 1.5 second timeout to smooth it out.

That's good enough for me, since the lag decreased from 30 seconds (with 10 audio elements on page) to just 1.5 seconds.